# How use { error } from useMutation and graphQL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, jsx, apollo-client

How can I use { error } from usemutation, so I have this:

```
....
import { CREATE_USER } from "../Graphql/Mutation";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
....
...


const [createUser, { error }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER);

...

const onSubmit = ( event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> ) => {
  if( !error ){
            createUser({
                variables: {
                name: name,
                username: userName,
                password: password,
                },
            });                          
            alert("New User");      
  }else{
     alert("usuario Registrado, ingrese otro usurname");
 }
}
```

so when I type inside inputs name="james" username="james01" password="123"  and I clicked on Button, the user is saved in database but if I try to type again the same user, I mean, I type this again name="james" username="james01" password="123", I should have an error, but I'm not it, why??

so my because the schema/mutation is like:

```
export const CREATE_USER = {
    type: MessageType,
    args: {
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        username: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString }
    },
    async resolve(parent: any, args: any){
        const { name, username, password } = args;
        const user = await Users.findOne({ username });
        if(!user){
            await Users.insert({ name, username, password });
            //console.log(name, username, password);
            return { successful: true, message: "New USERNAME" } 
        }else{
            return { successful: false, message: "USERNAME EXIST" } 
        }
    },
}
```

and mutation is like:

```
export const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation createUser($name: String!, $username: String!, $password: String!) {
    createUser(name: $name, username: $username, password: $password) {
      successful
      message
    }
  }
`;
```

so why??? I don't have a error?

How I can get the error??

Answer (score 0):

If you want an error returned you should throw one in your resolver:

```
...
  async resolve(parent: any, args: any){
      const { name, username, password } = args;
      const user = await Users.findOne({ username });
      if(user){
        throw new Error('USERNAME EXISTS');
      }
      await Users.insert({ name, username, password });
      //console.log(name, username, password);
      return { successful: true, message: "New USERNAME" } 
  },
```

Also in your frontend you have to make this async. Either with Promises or async/await.

```
const onSubmit = async ( event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> ) => {
  try {
    await createUser({
      variables: {
        name: name,
        username: userName,
        password: password,
      },
    });                          
    alert("New User");      
  } catch (err) {
    alert("usuario Registrado, ingrese otro usurname");
  }
}
```

There are multiple ways of doing this in React tho.
You should probably also block submit requests while the mutation is loading.